# PLSQL Execute Immediate Dynamic Aggregate Query and Bulk Collect

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to fetch the column's population (count of each column in a table) for many tables. I'm writing a PLSQL script which will create a dynamic query and want to print the result. Since my select query includes aggregate columns, I'm unsure how to define *TYPE*. Whether to use a cursor or execute immediate & bulk collect.

```
DECLARE
   V_COLUMN_NAME ALL_TAB_COLS.COLUMN_NAME%type;
   V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY varchar2(2000) := 'SELECT ';
   V_TABLE_NAME varchar2(200) := 'EMPLOYEE'; // Will be list of tables in future
   CURSOR TAB_COLS IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = V_TABLE_NAME;
  
BEGIN
   OPEN TAB_COLS;
   LOOP
      FETCH TAB_COLS INTO V_COLUMN_NAME;
      EXIT WHEN TAB_COLS%notfound;
      V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY := V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY ||'COUNT('|| V_COLUMN_NAME||'),';
   END LOOP;
  V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY:= SUBSTR(V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY, '0',LENGTH( V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY )-1);
  V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY:= V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY || ' FROM '|| V_TABLE_NAME; 
  

 //NEED A WAY TO EXECUTE DYNAMIC QUERY (variable V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY) and print the results.
 //SAMPLE DYNAMIC QUERY1 : SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID),COUNT(NAME),COUNT(BASE_URL),COUNT(INPUT_FORM),COUNT(BASE_URL_ASUCASE),COUNT(IS_CUSTOM) FROM EMPLOYEE 
 //SAMPLE DYNAMIC QUERY 2: SELECT COUNT(DEPT_ID),COUNT(NAME),COUNT(BASE_URL) FROM DEPT
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're going to have with this is the varying column list you want returned each time. So let's say you fix your immediate code concern with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY INTO var_employee_id,var_name,var_base_url,var_input_form,var_base_url_asucase,var_is_custom;
```

But then for the next one, you would need a different call:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY INTO var_dept_id,var_name,var_base_url;
```

Clearly you can't do this in a loop, since while the SQL statement itself is dynamic, the variables you fetch into are not. Reused dynamic SQL is expected to return the same structure in all cases, but you are changing the structure each time.

The most straight forward way to fix this is to query each column separately rather than trying to do all the columns in the table at once. That way, you select every column into a single number variable.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT_POPULATION_QUERY INTO var_column_count; -- one column only
```

But let's say that is a performance burden to you. If you really must combine all the columns in a single pass, then you have two approaches.

1. Determine the maximum number of columns you will ever have to query (hundreds, perhaps?). Create a record variable with that many number columns. While assembling your COUNT(column_name) list, count how many of these you append and then append dummy NULL columns however many times is needed to fill out the number of columns in you record type.

*OR*

2. Use a double nested dynamic SQL approach, where the entire PL/SQL block containing the dynamic SQL is itself dynamic SQL. Obviously you need the results to do something, so you'd have to process the results inside that block. Let's say you just need to enter them into a table.

   ```
    create table my_results (column_name varchar2(128),count_result integer);
    /
    DECLARE
      var_column_list varchar2(32767);
      var_variable_list varchar2(32767);
      var_plsql_block varchar2(32767);
      TYPE columns_tabtype IS TABLE OF varchar2(128);
      tab_columns columns_tabtype := columns_tabtype();
      var_table_name varchar2(128) := 'EMPLOYEE';
    BEGIN
      FOR rec_column IN (SELECT column_name,ROWNUM seq
                           FROM user_tab_columns
                          WHERE table_Name = var_table_name)
      LOOP
        var_column_list := var_column_list || 'COUNT('||rec_column.column_name||'),';
        var_variable_list := var_variable_list || 'C'||rec_column.seq||',';
        tab_columns.EXTEND;
        tab_columns(tab_columns.LAST) := rec_column.column_name;
      END LOOP;

      var_plsql_block := '
        DECLARE
          '||REPLACE(var_variable_list,',',' number;'||CHR(10))||'
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''SELECT '||RTRIM(var_column_list,',')||' FROM '||var_table_name||''' INTO '||RTRIM(var_variable_list,',')||';';

          FOR j IN tab_columns.FIRST .. tab_columns.LAST
          LOOP
            var_plsql_block := var_plsql_block ||'
              INSERT INTO my_results (column_name,count_result) VALUES ('''||tab_columns(j)||''',c'||j||');';
          END LOOP;

          var_plsql_block := var_plsql_block ||'
        END;
      ';

      --dbms_output.put_line(var_plsql_block); -- enable for debugging
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_plsql_block;
    END;
    /

    SELECT *
      FROM my_results
   ```

Having answered your question, I would end by asking whether you are approaching this problem correctly. You are essentially counting the number of non-NULL rows for each column. If that's all you need, then simply gather statistics on the table and you have your answers in user_tab_columns (the row_count from user_tables minus the num_nulls from user_tab_columns). That's a lot easier than you doing it yourself.

If you are instead trying to get the number of *distinct* values, then you'd have to add DISTINCT to each of your COUNT() functions, but again, it is easier to get that from num_distinct in user_tab_columns than to gather this info yourself. I've never in all my years had to do what you're trying to do, so maybe this is a problem you don't really need to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Create types first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object (table_name varchar2(30), column_name varchar2(30), cnt number);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function accepts table name as a parameter; then - in a loop - counts each column in that table, stores result into a collection which is `return` value:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return t_tab
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5    l_cnt number;
  6    l_tab t_tab := t_tab();
  7  begin
  8    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name, column_id
  9                  from user_tab_columns
 10                  where table_name = dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name)
 11                 )
 12    loop
 13      l_str := 'select count(' || cur_r.column_name || ') from ' ||cur_r.table_name;
 14      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 15
 16      l_tab.extend;
 17      l_tab(cur_r.column_id) := t_row(cur_r.table_name, cur_r.column_name, l_cnt);
 18    end loop;
 19
 20    return l_tab;
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(f_test('EMP'));

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                           CNT
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
EMP                            EMPNO                                  14
EMP                            ENAME                                  14
EMP                            JOB                                    14
EMP                            MGR                                    13
EMP                            HIREDATE                               14
EMP                            SAL                                    14
EMP                            COMM                                    4
EMP                            DEPTNO                                 14

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

You said (as comment in code you posted) that you'll use "list of tables" in the future. OK; function still accepts only one parameter, but it is you who should pass as many tables as you want.

For example:

```
SQL> select f.*
  2  from user_tables t cross join table(f_test(t.table_name)) f
  3  where t.table_name in ('DEPT', 'ORDERS');

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                           CNT
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
DEPT                           DEPTNO                                  4
DEPT                           DNAME                                   4
DEPT                           LOC                                     4
ORDERS                         STATE                                   3

SQL>
```

Comment: This is the single-column approach I mentioned in my answer. It's definitely the simplest and most robust approach. I went in a different direction however because it won't perform well if you have large tables with many columns. In my environment, billions of rows and a couple hundred columns is common. You wouldn't want to do a separate scan of the table for every column, so the OP's desire to get the counts of all columns in a single scan is something that can justifiably arise in the real world. For that, they would need nested dynamic SQL, which admittedly is more clunky but can perform.

Answer (score 0):

TO *count each column in a table* you do not need any PL/SQL script. Oracle is counting it for you already in the *object statistics* - either *approximately* with sampling - which can be perferctly OK for large tables or exactly with a scan of the whole table.

Technically you need the row count of a table and for each column the number of `NULL` values that you will subtract.

**Small Example**

```
create table tab as 
select 1 col1, 0 col2, 'X' col3 from dual union all
select 1,null, 'Y' from dual union all
select 3, null,null from dual;

select count(col1), count(col2), count(col3) from tab;
COUNT(COL1) COUNT(COL2) COUNT(COL3)
----------- ----------- -----------
          3           1           2
```

Gather statistics with 100% percent (exact, no sampling)

```
BEGIN 
   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>user, tabname=>'TAB',estimate_percent => 100);
END;
/
```

Now use the dictionary view to get the table `NUM_ROWS` and columns `NUM_NULLS` and subtract them to get the result.

```
select t.TABLE_NAME, t.NUM_ROWS, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.NUM_DISTINCT, c.NUM_NULLS, t.NUM_ROWS -  c.NUM_NULLS CNT_NOT_NULL
from user_tab_columns c
join user_tables t on t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_name = 'TAB';

TABLE_NAME   NUM_ROWS COLUMN_NAM NUM_DISTINCT  NUM_NULLS CNT_NOT_NULL
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------------
TAB                 3 COL1                  2          0            3
TAB                 3 COL2                  1          2            1
TAB                 3 COL3                  2          1            2
```

Note that as a bonus you get also the number of *distinct values* of each column. You may use sampling to get estimete values in less time or you may activate a *parallel option* to gather statistics.